# Can I add a script that is dynamically changed in a Sitecore layout page?

Tags: presentation, javascript

My company is still using Sitecore v8.2 and for a while we are not upgrading it.

Is there a way to add a script that has been created Front End side using Webpack and that has the following structure `<file_name>.<random_generated_string>.bundle.js`, where the "random_generated_string" is created at building time, when the solution is building the Front End stuff using Webpack, and add it to the Sitecore layout with the correct name each time there is a new build?

For example, when there is the first build on the Sitecore layout page I would like Sitecore to add the following script automatically:

```
...
<script src="~/FrontEnd/dist/js/index.57457932.bundle.js"></script>
...
```

But then in the next build I would like that Sitecore will add the new built Front End script:

```
...
<script src="~/FrontEnd/dist/js/index.99527463.bundle.js"></script>
...
```

Is it possible to do the same also with the styles that Webpack create as well and add the resulting file to the `head` of the layout page?

```
...
<link href="~/FrontEnd/dist/css/main.99527463.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
```

Comment: Change the webpack generation to remove the random string. If its there as a cache breaker, there are easier ways of doing that via adding a query string to the link ref in your code.

Comment: @RichardSeal Thanks for your reply, the meaning of that string is exactly the one you are mentioning. To let me understand better your suggestion, you are saying to add a query string using Sitecore, isn't it? How can I do that?